# Apache - redirecting with a new domain

Tags: apache, redirect, dns

We've had our site running on (say) stuff.com for a while, with a load of sub-domains for different applications, red.stuff.com, blue.stuff.com and of course a load of content stuff.com/things/in/my/head

We've recently purchased a new domain, awesome.com.

Can we configure Apache to replace the 'stuff.com' in any request that turns up, with 'awesome.com' permanently?  Would this method keep any search engine listings and existing links valid?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Apache's [rewrite engine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html).  Add this to your virtual server configuration (either in http.conf or in the sites-enabled directory):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} stuff.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{HTTP_HOST}$1 [C]
RewriteRule ^(.*)stuff.com(.*) http://$1awesome.com$2 [R,L]
```

The `[C]` chains the two rules together.  The first rule inserts the requested domain name into the request.  The next rule redirects the request to the new domain name, extracting the subdomain and the rest of the URL if necessary.

It should redirect any incoming request (I tested it with subdomains, files, and query strings in the URL), so the search engine links would still work.  I don't know how it affects search engine ranking, though.