# How to redirect urls old to new for e-commerce products urls?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

We have migrated one e commerce site to another e-commerce..

In that we have migrated entire products from old site to new site.. my products urls looks likes in old sites  below..

For that i want to write some condition.. like 
My incomming product urls look like this

--> www.oldSite.com/product/45687/genechip/ --> this is the url of old site

now i want to check the incommimg url comming like this or not in apache mod_rewrite.. i want to nnow  how to check inside this rewrite condition.. 
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (how to check my incomming url is matching or not here ).. if its true i have to redirect like below 
 --> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newSite.com/product/555f4/genechip  [L,R=301] ..

```
    pls help me out from this
```

ThanksInAdvance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache - redirecting with a new domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447624/apache-redirecting-with-a-new-domain)

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newSite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```